# Is it possible to set the position of a tab in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I want to set 2 tabs in above layout and 4 tab below layout as shown follow
is it possible in android.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Hellboy do you mean with the same Tabhost, unfortunately thats not possible... =(
but you will do your own implementation, check this...
[Customized Android Tabs](http://ezmobile.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/customized-android-tabs/)

Comment: In my spec I need to implement same User Interface. The other option for me is that put buttons in place of tab and put them in each xml file for the corresponding activity. If you know any better way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Android design library now includes [Tablayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) , use tablayout widget for desired output.